# Convert to module application- AngularJS module dependency

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, dependency-injection, angularjs-module

I started to remodel my AngularJS (fully working) page to modular version.

I grouped my files to 4 modules:

```
-band
-user
-layout
-core
```

And main app.js with:

```
(function () {
    angular.module('zt', [

        // shared modules

        'zt.core',

        'zt.user',
        'zt.band',
        'zt.layout'

        // other modules will be lazy-loaded from router
    ]);
})();
```

Each module has it own controllers, services etc. and own module config file:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('zt.user', []);
})();
```

And own route file:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
angular.module('zt.user')
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, AccessLevels) {

        $stateProvider
            .state('app.user', {
                abstract: true,
                template: '<ui-view/>',
                data: {
                    access: AccessLevels.user
                }
            })
```

`AccessLevels` is inside **zt.core** module and it is simple **constant**:

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    angular.module('zt.core')

        .constant('AccessLevels', {
            anon: 0,
            user: 1,
            mode: 2,
            admn: 3,
            suad: 4
        })
```

...

When I try to load page I've got an error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module zt
>   due to: Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module
>   **zt.user** due to: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: **AccessLevels**

All files are included ok

(also the same error in zt.band module)
All typing and including are ok.

When I add AccessLevels manual to zt.band and zt.user route configs another strange errors appears:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ztPlayerProvider <- ztPlayer
>   <- soundManagerDirective

and:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: AuthServiceProvider <-
>   AuthService <- ApplicationControler

**ztPlayer** is service **in the same module zt.layout with soundManagerDirective** !

and **AuthService** is inside shared **zt.core** module so it should be availiable inside ApplicationController inside **zt.layouts** module.

My include paths near end of the body tag:

```
<script src="/dist/js/core/core.module.js"></script>
        <script src="/dist/js/core/core.routes.js"></script>
        <script src="/dist/js/core/config.js"></script>
        <script src="/dist/js/core/config.lazyload.js"></script>

        <script src="/dist/js/core/services/auth.services.js"></script>
        <script src="/dist/js/core/services/storage.services.js"></script>
        <script src="/dist/js/core/services/ui-load.js"></script>

        <script src="/dist/js/core/controllers/auth.controller.js"></script>
        <script src="/dist/js/core/controllers/scroll.controller.js"></script>

        <script src="/dist/js/core/directives/auth.directives.js"></script>
        <script src="/dist/js/core/directives/main.directives.js"></script>
        <script src="/dist/js/core/directives/ui.directives.js"></script>
        <script src="/dist/js/core/directives/upload.directives.js"></script>

        <!-- /core module -->

        <!-- widget module -->

        <script src="/dist/js/widget/widget.module.js"></script>

        <!-- /widget module -->

        <!-- user module -->

        <script src="/dist/js/user/user.module.js"></script>
        <script src="/dist/js/user/user.routes.js"></script>

        <script src="/dist/js/user/services/user.services.js"></script>

        <script src="/dist/js/user/controllers/dashboard.controller.js"></script>
        <script src="/dist/js/user/controllers/profile.controller.js"></script>

        <!-- /user module -->

        <!-- band module -->

        <script src="/dist/js/band/band.module.js"></script>
        <script src="/dist/js/band/band.routes.js"></script>

        <script src="/dist/js/band/controllers/band.controller.js"></script>
        <script src="/dist/js/band/controllers/track.controller.js"></script>

        <script src="/dist/js/band/services/band.services.js"></script>
        <script src="/dist/js/band/services/song.services.js"></script>
        <script src="/dist/js/band/services/track.services.js"></script>

        <!-- /band module -->

        <!-- layout module -->

        <script src="/dist/js/layout/layout.module.js"></script>

        <script src="/dist/js/layout/services/player.services.js"></script>

        <script src="/dist/js/layout/controllers/application.controller.js"></script>
        <script src="/dist/js/layout/controllers/header.controller.js"></script>
        <script src="/dist/js/layout/controllers/message.controller.js"></script>

        <script src="/dist/js/layout/directives/player.directives.js"></script>
        <script src="/dist/js/layout/directives/setnganimate.directives.js"></script>

        <!-- /layout module -->

        <!-- other -->
        <script src="/dist/js/translate/translate.js"></script>
        <script src="/dist/js/filters/fromNow.js"></script>
```

I've tried a lot of things but nothing worked! I can't figure what is the problem of this.

Thanks!

Comment: you should place your `app.js` file at the end after loading all the modules..Rule of thumb before using module.it should initialize at-least

Comment: Thanks for reply, when a move app.js to the end another error appears: "Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'zt' is not available!" + error with AccessLevels not found.

Comment: looks like somewhere you are usinh module which haven't being initialized